# How to pass a value from a button to another class

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

Scenario: I have a series of jbuttons (created at runtime) and each of them has a number in his label. Buttons are created with this code:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= tablesNumber; i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Orders().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(button);
    }
```

I need to pass to the class Orders the number of the button which fires the event, e.g. if the user clicks on button number 5 I need to pass the value 5 to Orders.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is your question "how to access an orders object within a ActionListener?" or "How to get the number of the button that was pressed?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question:

> pass to the class Orders the number of the button which fires the event

You could just capture the loop iteration variable `i` so it can be used inside your anonymous event handler. For the sake of argument I have assumed you want to pass the number into the constructor, but you can use it however you like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= tablesNumber; i++) {
    final int t = i; // <-- NEW LINE HERE
    JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Orders(t).setVisible(true); // <-- USE t here however you need to
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(button);
}
```

Without `final int t = i` you may get the compiler error "Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method". This is because a capture variable (i.e. a variable from an outer scope used inside an anonymous class' method must be `final` (or effectively final - this behaviour has changed slightly as of SE 8).